# How does Jabba the Hutt survive on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, jabba-the-hutt

Business reasons aside, why would Jabba the Hutt live on Tatooine? [According to the Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hutt/Legends), he's a gastropod, and we know that salt kills slugs. Tatooine is a desert with two nearby suns, an environment slugs do not survive in.

Are there any explanations for *how* he and the other Hutts do not die in that environment?

Comment: He is not a slug. He is a Hutt.

Comment: He stays indoors.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - [No he doesn't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rR0b57coZFk)

Comment: @Valorum What you have shown me lies beyond the realm of that which I am willing to consider.

Comment: How does he not dry up?  Bathtubs full of moisturizer.  What, you didn't think the Twi'lek slave for was *just* dancing did you

Comment: The premise here just seems kind of silly and unfounded, what would make you think he's a gastropod? Just because the shape of his body is sort of slug-like, even if his arms, face, and dry-looking leathery skin bear no resemblance to a slug? That seems kind of like seeing a pink snake and concluding it must be a worm.

Comment: @Hypnosifl The Star Wars Essential Guide to alien species says Hutts *are* gastropods, so Michael B's premise sounds accurate to me.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - That's not canon any more, but that aside, looking at the entry on [google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Dw8GuPhsjkYC&lpg=PT95&pg=PT95#v=onepage&q&f=false) it does call them gastropods but also says "Physiologically, the Hutts are an anomaly, sharing traits from a variety of species" like sea mammals and marsupials. Then it says "scientists generally classify Hutts as gastropods because of the way they move, slithering around like giant slugs", suggesting "gastropod" is used pretty loosely in the Star Wars universe, so we can't assume it covers other Earth gastropod traits.

Comment: Also, EVERYONE calls Hutts "slugs".

Comment: @Wad Cheber - In Legends or current canon? Either way they're probably using it as an insulting name, kind of calling French people "frogs" though obviously more based on physical resemblance in the case of Hutts.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Disney canon.  And it is used by people who liked Jabba, too - like his Rancor trainer.

Comment: How does Jabba survive on Tatooine?  [He doesn't.](http://i.makeagif.com/media/8-09-2015/ZBzxiE.gif)

Comment: Jabba doesn't leave a slime trail, does he?

Comment: How does living in a climate-controlled building on a desert planet  = salt?

Answer (score 11):

Like most of the wealthy and corrupt of any species, (not that the two are associated by default) he throws money and/or henchmen at problems to solve them.

Additionally, as pointed out in the comments, he is a Hutt, and not a slug; as his physiology is the alpha predator of his planet's evolutionary testing ground, adaptability is requisite.

The question wouldn't then be much different then "how would humans survive?" To which the response is adapt ourselves, our tools, or our environment.

Comment: Some good points here. Could you expand your answer? :)

Comment: Sure, but I'll need to do it when I'm able to get to a computer :)

Comment: Great points. I updated my original post to include a citation from Wookiepedia, which is as far as I know one of the best sources for in-depth Star Wars information, which explicitly states that Hutts are gastropods.

Comment: @Michael B. - Only the Legends page on wookieepedia says Hutts are gastropods, not the canon page (see the two tabs at the top of the article). And see my earlier comment about how apparently in the Star Wars universe scientists call them gastropods "because of the way they move, slithering around like giant slugs", so no other aspects of Earth gastropods seems to be implied by this term.

Answer (score 9):

Even if Wookieepedia is right, they only say that the hutt are Gastropods

In our galaxy, Gastropod only means that he walk on his stomach (and Jabba certainly does it).

Gastropod doesn't mean that he is a slug, a snail, or whatever, nore it means that salt or the lack of water can kill him...

Even in our planet, some gastropod can live with very little water :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerocrassa_seetzeni

A lot of them live under the ocean (so they don't fear salt)

So Jabba may be a desert gastropod, or just rich enough to buy water, stay inside, have a shadowed barge, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Acording to the new canon novelisation of Star Wars: Return of the Jedi, Jabba's Palace (a former monastery) is kept cold, dark and moist, precisely the sort of conditions that would be most suitable for a giant slug to prevent them drying out.

> ***Just as a slug prefers to hide under a rock, Jabba has chosen a dark, damp place for his palace**. The nicer rooms are like a dungeon and the dungeon is…unspeakable.    It’s a fortress, really. So deep in the dunes that the desert itself is all the defense generally needed. Even so, under Jabba’s orders the old monastery was obsessively fortified by   master armorers.*
>
> *Yes, it’s the perfect place for this rancid crime lord to slither away and hide, wallowing in his slimy pleasures and chortling over his ill-gotten treasures.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that the Hutts came from a planet far more well suited to their physiology (as did many other species). In the case of the Hutts, it was likely the very fact that Tatooine is so inhospitable that made it desirable to them. The planet is sparsely populated, has an underdeveloped government system, and clearly has no real standing army. As such, it would be like a very underdeveloped nation in an inhospitable part of our planet. Why might a very wealthy family decide to live there? Because in that small pond, they immediately become a very big fish.

Real world example: Certain mafia families decided to set up operations in what was, at the time, the middle of nowhere in a desert backwater called Las Vegas. They invested huge amounts of money into building casinos thanks to the (at the time) unusual legal gambling laws there. Why would they do this? Because the smaller, less developed state made them more influential over the local government than they would be in a very developed place like New York.

I see the Hutts coming to Tatooine very much in that vein. It wasn't because the planet was hospitable to them, but because it was undeveloped and they could easily co-opt the levers of power. It was undeveloped because it was inhospitable, so in a way, they went there BECAUSE it was so harsh for them to live on.

Answer (score 0):

Because Tatooine is the home of prime hunter (Cantina is a good place to hire them) and black market area. Also there is many illegal activities on Tatooine and you know that Hutt clan are linked to.

Comment: that's a chicken and egg thing - does the Hutt presence beget scum and villainy surrounding it, or does scum and villainy attract the Hutt? I actually suspect the Hutt came first, then the scum filtered in.